# Map network drive what authentication twice

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share

I created a share folder on windows server 2012 and added a user for full permission on the share:
[image]

Then, when I try to map the drive the authentication appears twice.
The first authentication

[image]

After it passed, then it appears the second authentication windows
[image]

I do not know, which user should I enter here?

Comment: What type of user is this? Local or Domain user? Also: what's configured on the `Permissions` tab?

Comment: The user is domain user. In Permissiontab is configured as `Full Control`.

Comment: NTFS and Share level permissions match?

Comment: Where can I find out? As profile I choosed SMB Share - Quick.

Comment: That would be share permissions, so just open the properties, security tab

Comment: As you can see on the first picture, it is that what you mean?